# how to extract two components from HEX string , reverse XOR

Tags: c#, xor

My I need to generate a random 32 char HEX string.  I have code in place that will generate for example E272E28B8961FB155E3FC657831F0690

Now, I need to break this down into two 32 char strings such that value of string 1 XOR string 2 will = E272E28B8961FB155E3FC657831F0690

I seem to be having a hard time wrapping my head around that.   I suppose I need a reverse XOR on this string.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: A "Reverse XOR" is just XOR.  Also, a 16 character string XOR a 16 character string will yield a 16 character string, not a 32 character one.  Are you sure that is what you mean?

Comment: How can two 16 character strings XORed with each other become a 32 character string?

Comment: Thanks for point this out guys, I am very confused at the moment.   I mean to say 32 char strings.  The idea behind this is this, my string E272E28B8961FB155E3FC657831F0690 will get to a 3rd party.  Then I need to extract a 32 char string from this which will be mailed to Person A.   Another 32 char string mailed to person B.   They will then type this into an application.   If the XOR of Person A and Person B = 3rd party string the money will be transferred.

Comment: @Waddaulookingat: Don't just say that in a comment - you should be able to edit your question to update things and make it clearer what you are after.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want two 32 Hexadecimal Character strings (which is equivalent to 16 bytes) which will XOR to a known 32 Hexadecimal Character string, you can use this method.

Generate random bytes for the first part of the output, then calculate what the second part has to be based on the first part and the expected output.  XOR is a self-inverting operator (there's a fancy word for that that I'm forgetting) so it's fairly straightforward to do.

```
void q50415070()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var output = new byte[16];

    random.NextBytes(output);
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(output));
    // 91-77-E9-2F-EC-F7-8E-CC-03-AF-37-FD-4F-6F-D2-4D

    var part1 = new byte[16];
    random.NextBytes(part1);
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(part1));
    // 7A-9B-2B-8B-D7-CE-AA-7E-7E-C3-FE-FF-44-2A-21-3C

    var part2 = part1.Zip(output, (x, y) => (byte)(x ^ y)).ToArray();
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(part2));
    // EB-EC-C2-A4-3B-39-24-B2-7D-6C-C9-02-0B-45-F3-71
}
```

In this, `output` is the result I'm trying to reach, and `part1` and `part2` are the two components that I want to be able to XOR together to get the expected output.

I've used the Linq `Zip` method to combine the two `IEnumerable<byte>`s together element by element, then used the XOR operator `^` to calculate the result byte-by-byte.  Finally calling `ToArray()` to make it back into an array at the end.

This technique is used often in cryptography where you want to split an encryption key into two parts for two people to have, each of which is useless by itself.

Edit:  Tweaked the function slightly to more closely match your question:

```
void q50415070()
{
    var output = new byte[16] { 0xE2, 0x72, 0xE2, 0x8B, 0x89, 0x61, 0xFB, 0x15, 0x5E, 0x3F, 0xC6, 0x57, 0x83, 0x1F, 0x06, 0x90 };
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(output));
    // E2-72-E2-8B-89-61-FB-15-5E-3F-C6-57-83-1F-06-90

    var random = new Random();

    var part1 = new byte[16];
    random.NextBytes(part1);
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(part1));
    // 59-37-D0-A6-71-CC-6C-17-96-02-70-CE-A7-57-06-25

    var part2 = part1.Zip(output, (x, y) => (byte)(x ^ y)).ToArray();
    Debug.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(part2));
    // BB-45-32-2D-F8-AD-97-02-C8-3D-B6-99-24-48-00-B5
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Trevor.  You were right on the money this is cryto related stuff I am working on...The idea behind this is this, my string E272E28B8961FB155E3FC657831F0690 will get to a 3rd party. Then I need to extract a 32 char string from this which will be mailed to Person A. Another 32 char string mailed to person B. They will then type this into an application. If the XOR of Person A and Person B = 3rd party string the money will be transferred.  I will get back to you shortly if this kinda does what I want.

Comment: It might also be worth using the `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` instead of the `Random` to add security, depending on your process.